# touchableopacity is not working when offline

Tags: android, react-native, expo, touchableopacity, react-native-cli

touchableopacity is not working when offline, sometimes it take really slow like take a few minute to run onPress

```
<TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => this.example()}
      style={{padding: 10, justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#F26525', width: Dimensions.get('screen').width * 0.8, borderRadius: 3, marginTop: 15}}>
      <Icon name='refresh' size={20} color='#ffffff' />
      <Text style={{fontSize: 16, color: '#ffffff', fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Medium'}}> Try Again</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

i using :
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.55.1

i tried to change into touchablewithoutfeedback, but it still the same

thanks for your help ,

Answer (score 0):

You will have to bind your function like this.

```
<TouchableOpacity
      onPress={this.example.bind(this)}
      style={{padding: 10, justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#F26525', width: Dimensions.get('screen').width * 0.8, borderRadius: 3, marginTop: 15}}>
      <Icon name='refresh' size={20} color='#ffffff' />
      <Text style={{fontSize: 16, color: '#ffffff', fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Medium'}}> Try Again</Text>
```

or you can also bind your function in your constructor as well

```
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.example = this.example.bind(this)
}

<TouchableOpacity
      onPress={this.example}
      style={{padding: 10, justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#F26525', width: Dimensions.get('screen').width * 0.8, borderRadius: 3, marginTop: 15}}>
      <Icon name='refresh' size={20} color='#ffffff' />
      <Text style={{fontSize: 16, color: '#ffffff', fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Medium'}}> Try Again</Text>
```

or like this

```
<TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {console.log('Pressed!')}}
      style={{padding: 10, justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#F26525', width: Dimensions.get('screen').width * 0.8, borderRadius: 3, marginTop: 15}}>
      <Icon name='refresh' size={20} color='#ffffff' />
      <Text style={{fontSize: 16, color: '#ffffff', fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Medium'}}> Try Again</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use just one component inside the touchableOpacity so do this:

```
 <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => this.example()}
      style={{padding: 10, justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#F26525', width: Dimensions.get('screen').width * 0.8, borderRadius: 3, marginTop: 15}}>
      <View>
         <Icon name='refresh' size={20} color='#ffffff' />
         <Text style={{fontSize: 16, color: '#ffffff', fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Medium'}}> Try Again</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```